# Replace multiple columns with column mean of non-zero values

Tags: r, dataframe

I have data like so:

```
aye <- c(0,0,3,4,5,6)
bee <- c(3,4,0,0,7,8)
see <- c(9,8,3,5,0,0)
df <- data.frame(aye, bee, see)
```

I am looking for a concise way to create columns based on the mean for each of the columns in the data frame, where zero is kept at zero.

To obtain the mean excluding zero:

```
df2 <- as.data.frame(t(apply(df, 2, function(x) mean(x[x>0]))))
```

I can't figure out how to simply replace the values in the column with the mean excluding zero. My approach so far is:

```
df$aye <- ifelse(df$aye == 0, 0, df2$aye)
df$bee <- ifelse(df$bee == 0, 0, df2$bee)
df$see <- ifelse(df$see == 0, 0, df2$see)
```

But this gets messy with many variables - would be nice to wrap it up in one function.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why can't we just use

```
data.frame(lapply(dat, function (u) ave(u, u > 0, FUN = mean)))

#  aye bee  see
#1 0.0 5.5 6.25
#2 0.0 5.5 6.25
#3 4.5 0.0 6.25
#4 4.5 0.0 6.25
#5 4.5 5.5 0.00
#6 4.5 5.5 0.00
```

Note, I used `dat` rather than `df` as the name of your data frame. `df` is a function in R and don't mask it.

Comment: Or another option is `lapply(df, function(u) (!!u)*mean(u[u>0]))`

Comment: Yes, it is a double negation, first negation gives 0 values TRUE, so negate again to make it FALSE, but I guess your version is much better

Answer (score 1):

We can keep the result of apply function as numeric vector in `x`.

```
x <- apply(df, 2, function(x){ mean(x[x>0])})
df[which(df!=0, arr.ind = T)] <- x[ceiling(which(df!=0)/nrow(df))]

df
#  aye bee  see
#1 0.0 5.5 6.25
#2 0.0 5.5 6.25
#3 4.5 0.0 6.25
#4 4.5 0.0 6.25
#5 4.5 5.5 0.00
#6 4.5 5.5 0.00
```

Breaking the code down further to explain the working

Gives the indices where the value is not zero

```
which(df! = 0)
#[1]  3  4  5  6  7  8 11 12 13 14 15 16
```

This line decides which index we are going to select from `x`

```
ceiling(which(df!=0)/nrow(df))
#[1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3

x[ceiling(which(df!=0)/nrow(df))]
#aye  aye  aye  aye  bee  bee  bee  bee  see  see  see  see 
#4.50 4.50 4.50 4.50 5.50 5.50 5.50 5.50 6.25 6.25 6.25 6.25
```

Now substituting the above values where value isn't equal to 0 in the dataframe

```
df[which(df!=0, arr.ind = T)] <- x[ceiling(which(df!=0)/nrow(df))]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try rearranging what you already have into a `zeroless_mean` function, and then use `apply` on each column of your data.frame:

```
# Data
aye <- c(0,0,3,4,5,6)
bee <- c(3,4,0,0,7,8)
see <- c(9,8,3,5,0,0)
dff <- data.frame(aye, bee, see)

# Function
zeroless_mean <- function(x) ifelse(x==0,0,mean(x[x!=0]))

# apply
data.frame(apply(dff, 2, zeroless_mean))

# Output

  aye bee  see
1 0.0 5.5 6.25
2 0.0 5.5 6.25
3 4.5 0.0 6.25
4 4.5 0.0 6.25
5 4.5 5.5 0.00
6 4.5 5.5 0.00
```

I hope this helps.